# Dynamic Routing Show Searched Text In URL Angular 6

Tags: angular

I've a drop down which data is come from Database through WebAPI. If a user select any option so I'm searching the results from database and redirect him to the another page where is listing of results. Now my URL is static like example `http://localhost:4200/#/search` But I want to show selected text also in URL like `http://localhost:4200/#/search/selected%20text`. Please provide me some solutions thanks.

App.Module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'en',
    loadChildren: "src/app/views/site-feedback/site-feedback.module#SiteFeedbackModule"
  },
  {
    path: 'en',
    loadChildren: "src/app/views/privacy-policy/privacy-policy.module#PrivacyPolicyModule"
  },
  {
    path: 'en',
    loadChildren: "src/app/views/contact-us/contact-us.module#ContactUsModule"
  },
  {
    path: 'en',
    loadChildren: "src/app/views/data-coverage/data-coverage.module#DataCoverageModule"
  },
  {
    path: 'subscription',
    loadChildren: "src/app/views/subscribe/subscribe.module#SubscribeModule"
  },
  {
    path: 'en',
    loadChildren: "src/app/views/terms-conditions/terms-conditions.module#TermsConditionsModule"
  },
  {
    path: 'member',
    loadChildren: "src/app/views/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule"
  },
  {
    path: 'search',
    loadChildren: "src/app/views/result-listing/result-listing.module#ResultListingModule"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Route Parameters`.

The url can be `http://localhost:4200/#/search/selected%20text`, and in the routing file, the path can be

```
{
    path: 'search/:searchText',
    loadChildren: "src/app/views/result-listing/result-listing.module#ResultListingModule"
}
```

Then you can retrieve the `searchText` like this

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
...

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){ }

searchText: String;

ngOnInit() {
    this.searchText = this.route.snapshot.params['searchText'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass parameter into your routing file

```
 {
    path: 'search/:SearchText',
    loadChildren: "src/app/views/result-listing/result-listing.module#ResultListingModule"
  },
```

And pass the value for parameter from where you're navigating the component

```
constructor(private _router: Router){}
changeRecent(SearchText: string) {
    this._router.navigate(['/search', SearchText])
}
```